# Drawing Diagonal Lines Using Pillow - Python

Tags: python, function, python-imaging-library

I am stuck on the function black_stripe.

The goal is to get diagonal lines across the entire image, several diagonal lines evenly spaced apart.

I was able to get vertical lines across the entire image but for the black_stripe function was only able to get 1 diagonal line.

```
from PIL import Image
from random import randint

# vertical lines spaced 5 pixels apart
def black_vertical(image):
    image_path = " " # use your own path
    image_name = image

    im = Image.open(image_path + image_name)
    newim = Image.new(im.mode, im.size, color=0)

    pixarray = im.load()
    newpixarray = newim.load()

    for x in range(0, im.width, 5):
        for y in range(im.height):
            # get current pixel color
            pixel = pixarray[x, y]
            newpixel = pixel
            newpixel = (0,0,0)
            pixarray[x,y] = newpixel

    description = "black_vertical_"

    im.save(description + image_name)

def black_stripe(image):
    image_path = " " # use your own path
    image_name = image

    im = Image.open(image_path + image_name)
    newim = Image.new(im.mode, im.size, color=0)

    pixarray = im.load()
    newpixarray = newim.load()

    for x in range(im.height):
        pixel = pixarray[x, x]
        newpixel = pixel
        newpixel = (0,0,0)
        pixarray[x,x] = newpixel

    description = "black_stripe_"

    im.save(description + image_name)


def main():
    print('You will create a special image')
    picture = input('Please choose an image to start with\n')
    black_vertical(picture)
    black_stripe(picture)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Maybe use `ImageDraw.line()`

Comment: Ok, let me give that a try thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you still wanna do it manually, you'll need to check if you are on suitable diagonal. By suitable I mean the diagonal which satisfies **x + y = d** (where **x** and **y** are coordinates of the pixel you want to turn black and **d** is the number of the diagonal). And you want to repeat that for every next diagonal, which is s pixels apart. So the next one will be the one where **d' = d + s** and **x + y = d'** is satisfied.

```
next_diagonal = 0
space = 20
for x in range(0, image.width):
    # restart diagonal count
    next_diagonal = next_diagonal + space
    for y in range(0, image.height):
        if(x + y == next_diagonal):
            # insert your code for turning pixel black here:
            image[x,y] = (0, 0, 0)
            # find the next diagonal in the current column
            # you could even skip the next step if (next_diagonal + space > image.height)
            next_diagonal = next_diagonal + space
```

Diagonal thickness could also be controlled by introducing another variable diagonal_thickness = 5 and substituting condition with:

```
if (x + y >= next_diagonal or x + y < next_diagonal + diagonal_thickness):
```

This code will give you diagonals going from bottom left to top right. Try to modify it so you get diagonals from top left to bottom right. Good luck! :D